# Bin character variables in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a factor variable representing a vital sign. It has 50 levels. But, many levels are repetitive.For Eg: "Respiratory Rate" can be coded as "Resp Rate" or "RR" etc. I would like to group all respiratory rates into a single level and do the same for other vital signs. I tried the below method. Is there a better way to do this?

```
Sign_desc <- c("Resp rate:","Respiratory rate","Blood pressure panel","Systolic blood pressure", "Systolic blood pressure:", "Diastolic blood pressure","Diastolic blood pressure:","resp rate")  

Sign_Value <- c(10,  12, "80/120", 120, 120,  80,  80, 15)   
Vital_Sign <- as.data.frame(cbind(Sign_desc,Sign_Value))

Vital_Sign$Sign_desc[Vital_Sign$Sign_desc=="Respiratory Rate"] <- "RR"
Vital_Sign$Sign_desc[Vital_Sign$Sign_desc=="Resp Rate:"] <- "RR"
Vital_Sign$Sign_desc[Vital_Sign$Sign_desc=="resprate"] <- "RR"
```

Comment: there is not a magic function, please make your example reproducible

Comment: `grep`/`grepl`, probably. It's probably faster to assign directly to the factor levels instead of the values, too, but be careful of your order or you'll mess up your data.

Comment: @rawr Made the example reproducible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `levels` to directly access the factors levels rather than modifying the data itself:

```
levels(Vital_Sign$Sign_desc)[levels(Vital_Sign$Sign_desc)=="Respiratory Rate"] <- "RR"
levels(Vital_Sign$Sign_desc)[levels(Vital_Sign$Sign_desc)=="Resp Rate"] <- "RR"
levels(Vital_Sign$Sign_desc)[levels(Vital_Sign$Sign_desc)=="resprate"] <- "RR"
```

To do it all at once:

```
levels(Vital_Sign$Sign_desc)[levels(Vital_Sign$Sign_desc) %in% c("Respiratory Rate", "Resp Rate","resprate")] <- "RR"
```

Answer (score 2):

A more automated yet less explicit way than @HubertL's method would be to use string distances.

```
Sign_desc <- c("Resp rate:","Respiratory rate","Blood pressure panel",
               "Systolic blood pressure", "Systolic blood pressure:",
               "Diastolic blood pressure","Diastolic blood pressure:","resp rate")

ad <- adist(Sign_desc)
rownames(ad) <- Sign_desc

hc <- hclust(as.dist(ad))
plot(hc)
rect.hclust(hc, 3)
```

[image]

Based on the plot above, 3 groups might be appropriate, so you can then use `cutree` to see which strings will fall into which groups

```
(ct <- cutree(hc, 3))
# Resp rate:          Respiratory rate      Blood pressure panel 
#          1                         1                         2 
# Systolic blood pressure  Systolic blood pressure:  Diastolic blood pressure 
#                       3                         3                         3 
# Diastolic blood pressure:                 resp rate 
#                         3                         1
```

And you can use these groups to give your new names in order. From above, I want RR to correspond to the 1s, BP to the 2s and 3s, etc.

```
## new names corresponding to the groups above
nn <- c('RR', 'BP', 'BP')

cbind(old = Sign_desc, new = nn[ct])
#       old                         new 
# [1,] "Resp rate:"                "RR"
# [2,] "Respiratory rate"          "RR"
# [3,] "Blood pressure panel"      "BP"
# [4,] "Systolic blood pressure"   "BP"
# [5,] "Systolic blood pressure:"  "BP"
# [6,] "Diastolic blood pressure"  "BP"
# [7,] "Diastolic blood pressure:" "BP"
# [8,] "resp rate"                 "RR"
```

Here is all the code used

```
Sign_desc <- c("Resp rate:","Respiratory rate","Blood pressure panel","Systolic blood pressure", "Systolic blood pressure:","Diastolic blood pressure","Diastolic blood pressure:","resp rate")
ad <- adist(Sign_desc)
rownames(ad) <- Sign_desc
hc <- hclust(as.dist(ad))
plot(hc)
rect.hclust(hc, 3)
(ct <- cutree(hc, 3))
nn <- c('RR', 'BP', 'BP')
cbind(old = Sign_desc, new = nn[ct])
```